# How do I tell why a systemd service was started?

Tags: centos7, systemd

I am trying to figure out why a specific service is started on a system, and I wonder if there is a command to tell why a specific service was started?

When asking for status on the service, systemctl claims that it is disabled, yet it is running and I haven't explicitly asked to start it, AFAICT. Output below (slightly anonymized)

```
# systemctl status myservice
● myservice.service - My Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since mån 2017-02-27 13:57:15 CET; 30min ago
     Docs: http://www.example.com/
 Main PID: 4680 (ewe)
   CGroup: /system.slice/myservice.service
           ├─4680 /opt/myservice/vbc/bin/myservice
           └─4944 /opt/myservice/vbc/bin/myservice
```

I **am** starting a service that has set `Before=myservice.service` in its `.service` file (no `Requires`), so I am suspecting that, but I can't tell for sure.

This is running on a CentOS 7.3 system.

*EDITED:* I have been able to work around the issue by making sure that a service that the above service has a `Requires=`, `After=` and `Wants=` relationship to, and which is started by a transient run-once service, is explicitly stopped. When doing this, the service is not started. I am not closer to figuring out *why* it was started in the first place, however.

*EDITED:* It seems that my service file is **started** whenever one of the
services it has a `Requires` relationship to is restarted. I did not expect
that to happen, I assumed that it would only mean that my service would
start the other service when started, not that it would also start mine.
Removing `Requires` fixes the phantom restarts.

Comment: `Before` shouldn't cause `myservice.service` to run if it wouldn't run anyway. It just means "If we are starting Y, start X before it". http://serverfault.com/questions/812584/in-systemd-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-requires/812589#812589

Comment: Exactly, that is why I am a bit baffled as to why the service is starting. It shouldn't be.

Answer (score 5):

Running `sudo systemctl status` might help, as might `systemctl list-dependencies`.

I had heard of services being started on install on (I think) Ubuntu, but never on CentOS.
However, *IF* your service has a socket unit defined, then traffic to a given socket/port could be causing your service to start automatically.

I have such a setup for TFTP, for example:

`sudo systemctl list-dependencies | grep socket`

```
│ ├─sockets.target
│ │ ├─dbus.socket
<snip>
│ │ └─tftp.socket
```

Config for it says to start the service if UDP/69 traffic is received:

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/tftp.socket
[Unit]
Description=Tftp Server Activation Socket

[Socket]
ListenDatagram=69

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: Bonus points for the bit about the socket, I was struggling to understand why syslog-ng was getting restarted after explicitly stopping it and that turned out to be the answer.

Comment: What if list-dependencies doesn't show the service at all?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow did you ever find the answer? I also see a service started (despite manually disabling it) and not shown in list-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Another reason why a service could be started, which would not be reflected in `systemctl list-dependencies`, is if it is a D-Bus service which got started on-demand. For instance, looking at the [UPower daemon](https://upower.freedesktop.org/) on my system, we can see it is running, yet is not enabled:

```
systemctl status upower
  ● upower.service - Daemon for power management
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/upower.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
       Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-04-07 10:56:33 EDT; 12h ago
```

Moreover, we can see that the systemd service exposes a D-Bus interface using the [BusName](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) option:

```
$ systemctl cat upower
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/upower.service
[Unit]
Description=Daemon for power management
Documentation=man:upowerd(8)
  
[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.freedesktop.UPower
ExecStart=/usr/lib/upowerd
Restart=on-failure
```

Finally—and most importantly—we can see in the system log that it is [dbus-daemon](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html) which starts our service.

```
Apr 07 10:56:33 comet-observatory-laptop dbus-daemon[319]:
[system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service' requested by ':1.22' (uid=1000 pid=490 comm="workrave")
```