# is it possible for nginx to load certs from a url

Tags: nginx, ssl

We host many different domains and currently the certs live in a database. It's becoming increasingly tedious to get the certs out of there and into files just so nginx can load them.

It would be much nicer if we could something like the following:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen   443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate_key https://cert-distributor.acme.com/$host/server.key;
    ssl_certificate https://cert-distributor.acme.com/$host/server.crt;
...
}
```

Bonus points if the cert is cached in case `cert-distributor.acme.com` is down.

Comment: Is it even documented? )

Comment: `engine:name:id` and `data:$variable` look promising and that's assuming there isn't some other way I know nothing about.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate : "Syntax: ssl_certificate _file_"

Answer (score 1):

**Answer.** Short. It is not. At the moment of writing this post, the [documentation stays](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate):

> `Syntax: ssl_certificate file;`

**Workarounds.** There are various workarounds for your problem. I would call some of them a *preferred way to do it*. So, order matters.

- You can certificates deployment with Ansible, Salt or Chef; and keep them locally, on the host **only**.
- You can override `nginx` `systemd`-unit that [requires](https://serverfault.com/questions/812584/in-systemd-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-requires) downloading a file from `URL` to specific path and restart `nginx`.
- You can make a [`systemd-timer`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers), that downloads certificate and restarts `nginx`.

*Note.* Remember about security of *the endpoint* and *Man in the middle attacks*. More-over. How would you authenticate if specific host is allowed to download a file or not? Kerberos?