# Does systemd fail if a dependency in After=/Requires= doesn't exist?

Tags: systemd

I have a service A that runs in a limited number of environments to provision a host with some files. I have another service B that runs in all environments. I'd like B to depend on (and only start after) A if they are both running in the same environment.

I thought to simply add an `After=A` and `Requires=A` to B based on the ​answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/931383/151560)

> - `After` only checks if the unit is activated already, and does not explicitly activate the specified units.
> - The units listed in `Requires` are activated together with the unit. If any of the required units fail to start, the unit is not activated.

which seems to indicate that both of these, `After=` and `Requires=`, are needed to ensure a dependency is started before *this* (B) unit.

But what happens if that specified unit doesn't exist, ie. in the environment where service A doesn't run? Is the dependency a no-op?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least as of systemd v219:

- Adding an `After=A` to B is harmless when A does not exist; B will still start.
- Adding a `Requires=A` to B is [mostly harmless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Mostly_Harmless) when A does not exist; when B is started, you'll get a message in the journal to the effect: *"Cannot add dependency job for unit b.service, ignoring: Unit not found."* but B will still be started.

Note that the [Requires=](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=) option ties closely to the [Type=](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) option!

- If service A is a "simple" type (the default), systemd will consider it activated as soon as the ExecStart process is forked off, which is *before* that service has finished doing its work!
- If service A is instead a "forking" type, then systemd "will consider the unit started when the parent process exits", which is probably what you want in this case.

Comment: For short "provisioning" scripts, Type=oneshot would be the preferred choice, behaving somewhat like Type=forking but _actually meant_ to go directly back to inactive when the script is done. Using Type=forking with something that doesn't leave a daemon running is a bit of a weird hack.