# Replacement of "su - user -c command" in systemd unit

Tags: linux, systemd, su

Having read that using `su -` as part of an `ExecStart=` (`ExecStop=`) in a `systemd` unit is a bad idea, I wonder what the proper replacement is.

When using some vendor-supplied scripts or commands (where the vendor failed to provide proper systemd units), re-writing those scripts or commands for `systemd` is not an option (support-wise, and update-wise).

The problem is that during "login" of the user that runs the service, additional scripts set up various environment variables, depending on OS, etc. (that's why I ask about `su - user -c command`, and not about `su user -c command`).
Of course I could output the "normal environment" and save that in a file (for importing into `systemd`), but after a change in those vendor scripts, I would have to re-sync the environment file each time.

So what's the best I can do instead?

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the user under which account is to be executed in your systemd unit

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
Group=mygroup
ExecStart=/path/to/my/script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You are assuming the user's scripts in `$HOME` do set set up any important environment variables. If it were that simple, I would not have asked!

Answer (score 0):

It is not `su` that sets up the environment here; it's all done by the shell that 'su' invokes with the "login" option (either `-l` or more traditionally `argv[0][0] == '-'`) for handling of the `-c` command.

The same can be achieved by running `/bin/sh -l -c "command"` through any other method that switches the UID and pre-sets $HOME, e.g.:

```
User=foo
Environment=HOME=/home/foo
ExecStart=/bin/sh -l -c "printenv"
```

util-linux has `runuser` which works similarly to `su` but is less likely to have the undesired PAM modules enabled. It sets $HOME automatically. (It also has a `-l` but strangely it conflicts with `-u`.)

```
# runuser -u foo -- /bin/sh -l -c "printenv"
```